# BOOTMGR missing after installation of Boot-repair: Ubuntu 14.04 onpre-existing Windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I have encountered this problem on my notebook (with pre-existing Windows 7). Initially, I wanted to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows, and the Ubuntu installation went well.

However, when I wanted to access Windows, I could no longer do so (Ubuntu works just fine). So, I did some googling and found the Boot-repair ISO file and did a boot-repair. It was shown that the boot repair was successful, but when I restarted my notebook again, I was met with "BOOTMGR is missing".

My boot details is as follows: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8049879

I'd still like to have access to both Ubuntu and Windows 7.

Regards,
Kester

Comment: If an answer helped you, please mark it as accepted. If it didn't, please comment to that point. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Semi-easy (I think)

1. Grab your Windows 7 Install Disc and repair the Windows install. It will automatically recreate the boot table.
2. Grab your Ubuntu Install Disc and open a commandline. In that, type `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`.
3. Boot into Ubuntu and  open up a commandline. Run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Hi Whaaaat, 

Many thanks for the input, I have been inundated with work for the last few weeks, I will be following your instruction and report back if it works. 

So far, I have brought my notebook to a computer shop, where the technician said all my files are lost. I hope this is not the case, as I certainly did not move/delete my files during the Ubuntu partition, unless Ubuntu wipes all my files without warning me. But he was confident that all he could detect was Ubuntu and absolutely no Windows files were found.

- Kes